# Define a variable of one class from another class

Tags: c#, class, oop

So following is the set up of different classes that I need to create:

```
Author – AuthorId, AuthorName, DateOfBirth, State, City, Phone.
Publisher – PublisherId, PublisherName, DateOfBirth, State, City, Phone.
Category – CategoryId, CategoryName, Description.
Book – BookId, Category, Title, Author, Publisher, Description, Price, ISBN, PublicationDate.
```

Now as you can see Author in Book and AuthorId in Author classes are the same.How to achieve this in C#

Comment: If you set the AuthorId on the author object, and then set the Author variable = to the author object, the book object would then contain an author object that has the AuthorId set to the value you put in Author-AuthorId.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am asking to replicate the functionality of foreign key of sql in C#. That is how to use a variable of one class in another one.

Comment: @DiscoDancer Check my answer, I believe it should clarify your doubts about how to design in OOP world ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to distinguish *relational design* from *object-oriented design*.

Object-oriented programming (from now just ***OOP***) isn't relational but **hierarchical**, thus, there's no concept of *foreign key*.

Also, in OOP there're two kinds of *relations* between objects:

- **Inheritance**. If you've implemented two classes `A` and `B` and you can say that `B` is `A`, then you need to use  *inheritance*. For example, a `Cat` **is** an `Animal`.
- **Composition**. If you've implemented two classes `A` and `B` and you can say that `A` **has** a `B`, then you need to use *composition*. For example, a `Car` has a `Wheel`.

Now take these rules and try to apply them to your particular case:

- A `Book` **has** an `Author`. Bingo! You need to use *composition*.

Composition is expressed by declaring a property of the class that's owned by the enclosing type.

In your case:

```
public class Book
{
     public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

While the following code sample **would be wrong**:

```
public class Book
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

...because OOP **is hierarchical**, thus, **you don't search the author associated to the `Book`, but you traverse `Book` to get `Author`'s information**.

In other words, in OOP your *foreign key* is an *object reference* to the associated object.

Let's see a summary of how to do things in the right way in OOP when you want to get the `Author` of a given `Book`:

```
BookRepository bookRepo = new BookRepository();
Book book = bookRepo.GetById(302);
Author author = book.Author;
```

Now let's see a **wrong** sample:

```
BookRepository bookRepo = new BookRepository();
Book book = bookRepo.GetById(302);

AuthorRepository authorRepo = new AuthorRepository();
Author author = authorRepo.GetById(book.AuthorId);
```

Don't you feel that last *wrong* sample doesn't feel natural in OOP world? Why you need to perform an additional query to get the whole `Author` object? This feels very relational!

In the other hand, there's nothing wrong with associating an unique identifier to `Author` or any object, because you need to uniquely distinguish each one from others, and, in addition, the underlying data storage might by relational and may need to store and retrieve objects based on their *primary key*/*foreign key*.

### OP has also asked on some comment...

> What if I only want to give the book object access only to authorid
>   and nothing else. Because by this method I am able to access all of
>   author's elements.

Welcome to the world of *interfaces*. One of their use cases is *publishing* information. Or, in other words, *publishing just what you want to publish*:

```
public interface IUniquelyIdentifiable
{
     int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Author : IUniquelyIdentifiable
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     // ...and the rest of properties
}
```

Now you just need to associate `IUniquelyIdentifiable` to `Book` instead of `Author`:

```
public class Book
{
     public IUniquelyIdentifiable Author { get; set; }
}
```

...and you can still set a full `Author` on `Book`:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.Author = new Author();
```

This will *hide* everything excepting `Author.Id`, while in some parts of your code you can cast `IUniquelyIdentifiable` to `Author`:

```
// It'll set null to the whole variable if the 
// implementation of IUniquelyIdentifiable isn't Author
Author author = book.Author as Author;
```

BTW you need to be cautious if you're going to use an [OR/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), because it may be harder to map your object model to the target relational model.

IMHO, as a general rule, I wouldn't hide object properties for objects that can be persistent (i.e. those that can be saved to a database).

Comment: Hey nice and informative answer.But i have one doubt regarding this. What if I only want to give the book object access only to authorid and nothing else. Because by this method I am able to access all of author's elements.

Comment: @DiscoDancer You can use interfaces to hide information. Let me update the answer to explain it better, hold 5 minutes :)

Comment: @DiscoDancer Ok see the update at the bottom of the answer

Comment: hey i also found out that if set other properties to private,you cant access.Do u see any advantages of your method of interfaces against the use of this private keyword?

Comment: @DiscoDancer The problem with private properties is that you won't be able to set them outside the whole class...

Answer (score 5):

Your `Book` object could have a reference to the `Author` inside the class, as shown below.

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
   private Author _author { get; set; }

   public Book(Author author)
   {
     _author = author;
   }

   public void PrintBookAuthor()
   {
     Console.WriteLine(_author.AuthorName);
   }
}
```

Then to setup:

```
Author author = new Author();
author.AuthorName = "Darren Davies";

Book programmingBook = new Book(author);
programmingBook.PrintBookAuthor();
```

Comment: i dont want to use the variable in the class constructor but outside it.How to do it?

Comment: @DiscoDancer - you could change the access modifier to `public` rather than `private` and access the `author` object directly from the `Book` class, but IMO this breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Like this -->>public Author _author { get; set; }                                                        -->>public _author.AuthorId {get; set;} .....??

Comment: @DiscoDancer - yes.  If you are making it public, it could be renamed to `Author` rather than `_author` to conform to C# naming conventions.

Comment: Its showing error that _author is not an interface when i write -->>public _author.AuthorId {get; set;}

Comment: @DiscoDancer - it should be `public Author Author { get; set; }` - You will also have to set this  variable when you instantiate your `Book` object.

Comment: int Author.AuthorId { get; set; } -->> showing error

Comment: @DiscoDancer - because Author.AuthorId is not a valid property name.  Please read comment above and look at the answer I've provided.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Private properties starting with `_` isn't a .NET convention. Property identifiers are homogeneous independently of property's access modifier :/