# How to create 2 generic class that will handle 2 different classes initialisation?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have 3 types of operation :Add,Multiply and Division

Below are the classes to handle this 3 operation:

```
public class Add
{
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public Add(int value)
   {
      Value=value;
   }
}
```

This below class will be called by above main class:

```
class Source : Add
{
   public Source(int value1)
          :base(value1)
   {
   }
}

class Destination : Add
{
    public Destination(int value2)
          :base(value2)
   {
   }
}
```

I am calling above class like this:

```
Add addObj1 = new Source(10);
Add addObj2 = new Destination(20);
int c=addObj1.Value + addObj2.Value;
```

Now i have another class like below:

```
public class Multiply
{
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public Multiply(int value)
   {
       Value=value;
   }
}

class Source1 : Multiply
{
   public Source(int value1)
          :base(value)
   {
   }
}

class Destination1 : Multiply
{
    public Destination1 (int value2)
          :base(int value2)
   {
   }
}
```

Now when i am trying to call this class like this:

```
Multiply multiplyObj1 = new Source(10); //This is always referring to Source of Add class
 Multiply multiplyObj2 = new Destination(5); //This is always referring to Destination of Add class
```

Now when i rename **Source and Destination with Source1 and Destination1** and call like this then it is working:

```
Multiply multiplyObj1 = new Source1(10); //Working
Multiply multiplyObj2 = new Destination1(5); // Working
int c= multipleObj1.Value * multiplyObj2.Value;
```

**Note**:Right now i have created 4 class in which Source and Destination will handle Add class and Source1 and destination1 will handle Multiply

I am talking about how to reuse 2 class for both Add and Multiply class or for other class too(For Division etc..).

Now if i want to perform Division then i have again create 2 more class to handle division.

So here i dont want to duplicate **Source and Destination** i.e instead of creating 4 class i.e **Source,Destination,Source1 and Destination1**  is it possible to create only **2 generic class i.e Source and Destination** that will perfectly handle **both Add and Multiple**???

Comment: Please post actual C# code. What kind of syntax is how you declare your classes... ?:(

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer :Sorry but i have posted the code which i am using right now and i didnt got you what you are saying

Comment: your code doesn't compile. It's not actual C#!!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer :Sorry there was some syntax mistake but now updated.Check now

Comment: BTW it has been already marked as a duplicate. If you find any other issue with your code you can post a new question :\

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer:But i dont have any issue with this code.It is just that i dont want to create duplicate class.So any idea or suggestion for this??

Comment: Ok now I see why @Heinzi has marked it as duplicate. From your words, someone can understand that you want a way of deriving a class from two base classes. But you're asking for how to solve this with generics or with any other approach.

Comment: See my answer and let's discuss if it's what you're looking for with your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120537/discussion-between-learning-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's summarize your issue now that you've already edited your question and you've added meaningful names to your classes.

You need to...

- Perform *additions*.
- Perform *multiplications*.

And you want to define base class to rule them all.

First of all, there's an issue here. You can't say that an *addition source* and a *multiplication source* **are *additions* and *multiplications* altogether**.

It's like saying that a *cat* is both an animal and a mineral. No, it's an animal.

This situation translated to object-oriented programming world means **multiple inheritance**:

```
// WRONG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! C# doesn't support multiple inheritance
public class Source : Addition, Multiplication 
{
}
```

BTW, a source of additions couldn't also a source of multiplication. It's not a technical limitation, **but a semantic limitation**. It's just not right. **Your design is simply wrong.**

So, what? Well, I believe that you need to refactor your idea and code and you'll get what you want.

For example, if any math operation **source** has the same form, I would define a class to value sources:

```
public class Source
{
    public Source(int value) 
    {
         Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
}
```

And then I would define `Multiply` and `Add` classes based on an `Operation` class:

```
public abstract class Operation
{
      public Operation(Source sourceA, Source sourceB)
      {
           SourceA = sourceA;
           SourceB = sourceB;
      }

      public Source SourceA { get; }
      public Source SourceB { get; }

      public abstract int Do();
}

public class Add : Operation
{
      public Operation(Source sourceA, Source sourceB) : base(sourceA, sourceB)
      {
      }

      public override int Do() => SourceA.Value + SourceB.Value;
}

public class Multiply : Operation
{
      public Operation(Source sourceA, Source sourceB) : base(sourceA, sourceB)
      {
      }

      public override int Do() => SourceA.Value * SourceB.Value;
}
```

Now you've a single source for your mathematical operations and just a base class to summarize there what's common to any operation, and two operations already implemented.

Note that you can take advantage of *polymorphism* since any operation inherits `Operation`:

```
Source sourceA = new Source(203);
Source sourceB = new Source(134);

Operation op1 = new Multiply(sourceA, sourceB);
Operation op2 = new Add(sourceA, sourceB);

int result1 = op1.Do();
int result2 = op2.Do();
```

I believe that this could be a possible and acceptable design.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your actual use case doesn't love *inheritance* and you need to go with *composition*. Please double-check this other answer I did some days ago: [Define a variable of one class from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815425/define-a-variable-of-one-class-from-another-class/38815981#38815981)

Let's use a real-world case: a `Car`.

A `Car` has...

- `Engine`
- `Radio`
- `Wheel`

It wouldn't be correct to say that a concrete `Car` should inherit `Engine`, `Radio` and `Wheel`, because a `Car` has them, but they're not cars, but parts of the whole `Car`.

When you arrive to this conclusion is because you need *composition*:

```
public class Car
{
     public Engine Engine { get; set; }
     public Wheel Wheel { get; set; }
     public Radio Radio { get; set; }
}
```

That way, a concrete car, let's say a `Ferrari`, can *inherit* everything a `Car` has by default and it can also *add more components*:

```
public class FerrariTestarossa : Car
{
     // More properties and methods that make a FerrariTestarossa unique
     // from a generic car
}
```

Probably you can extrapolate this to your own use case.